# Tornado coroutine with websockets not working with python3

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

The `HandlerWebsockets` does work fine and is just replying with what has been send at the moment throught `messageToSockets(msg)`. However both tries to send messages to the websocket from the coroutine of the web application are not working. Looks like everything is blocked by these attempts...

```
class webApplication(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r'/', HandlerIndexPage),
            (r'/websocket', HandlerWebSocket, dict(msg='start')),
        ]

        settings = {
            'template_path': 'templates'
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

    @gen.coroutine
    def generateMessageToSockets(self):
        while True:
            msg = str(randint(0, 100))
            print ('new messageToCon: ', msg)
            yield [con.write_message(msg) for con in HandlerWebSocket.connections]
            yield gen.sleep(1.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ws_app = webApplication()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(ws_app)
    port = 9090
    print('Listening on port:' + str(port))
    server.listen(port)
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(webApplication.generateMessageToSockets)
    IOLoop.current().set_blocking_log_threshold(0.5)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Here the WebSockets Handler

```
class HandlerWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    connections = set()

    def initialize(self, msg):
        print('HWS:' + msg)

    def messageToSockets(self, msg):
        print ('return message: ', msg)
        [con.write_message(msg) for con in self.connections]

    def open(self):
            self.connections.add(self)
            print ('new connection was opened')
            pass

    def on_message(self, message):
            print ('from WebSocket: ', message)
            self.messageToSockets(message)

    def on_close(self):
            self.connections.remove(self)
            print ('connection closed')
            pass
```

I am a bit lost in the examples, questions here, documentation etc. So any hint how to properly start a continous calling websocket routine is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generateMessageToSockets` will loop endlessly, generating messages as fast as it can without waiting for those messages to be sent. Since it starts first and never yields, the HTTPServer will never actually be able to accept a connection.

If you really want to send messages as fast as you can, the minimal solution without blocking would be

```
yield [con.write_message(msg) for con in HandlerWebSocket.connections]
yield gen.moment
```

But it would probably be better to use `gen.sleep` to send messages at regular intervals, instead of "as fast as possible".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's just a reduced example hello world like example. The production code will only send rarely updates. Changed the code/posting accordingly . Unfortunately still can't see any print on the command line or generated replies through the routine

Comment: and finally I have tp appologise, actually your suggestion does work on python 3.6.5 and tornado 5.1.. sorry I have to change the plattform far to often

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately all the gen.routines tries didn't work for me. Moved back to threads

```
def generateMessageToSockets():
    while True:
        msg = str(randint(0, 100))
        print ('new messageToCon: ', msg)
        [con.write_message(msg) for con in HandlerWebSocket.connections]
        sleep(1.0)


class WebApplication(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r'/', HandlerIndexPage),
            (r'/websocket', HandlerWebSocket, dict(msg='start')),
        ]

        settings = {
            'template_path': 'templates'
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tGenarate =  threading.Thread(target=generateMessageToSockets)
    tGenarate.start()
    ws_app = WebApplication()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(ws_app)
    port = 9090
    print('Listening on port:' + str(port))
    server.listen(port)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

which works

Comment: for those seeing it later that did work with Python 3.5.4 /Tornado 4.5.1 not with python 3.6.5 / tornado 5.1...